# Can't Navigate to next Frame

Tags: wpf, navigation, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I've got a problem with navigate to next page in section:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
            Debug.WriteLine("Test1");
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(LoginView));
            Debug.WriteLine("Test2");            
    }
```

The method Frame.Navigate didn't work at all if only it's call in OnNavigatedTo. On debug I see "Test1" and "Test2" but nothing else happens.
Any idea? The project: Windows Phone Store App 8.1

Comment: Does the LoginView inherit from a Page class?

Comment: Yes, it does. Any other idea?

Comment: Yes, it works! Thanks. I put it into RunAsync method :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add async keyword to OnNavigatedTo method and add await Task.Delay(10); before Frame.Navigate() call. Alternatively, you can execute Frame.Navigate() in Dispatcher.

**1) using delay**

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(10);
    Frame.Navigate(typeof (LoginView));
}
```

**2) using Dispatcher**

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(LoginView));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the very same issue and it was caused because I had some Xaml not being resolved properly on second page. Check for Xaml being proper and all resource and references being right.